# Django ORM group by week day and sum the day of each separately

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am having trouble to query based on weekday.

This is my models:

```
class Sell(models.Model):
    total_sell = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and this is my query:

```
        weekly_sell = Sell.objects.annotate(
            weekday=ExtractWeekDay('date'),
            total=Sum('total_sell')
        ).values(
            'weekday',
            'total'
        )
```

But data i am getting and it is not my expected.

Like I have an entry in the table

```
Sunday sell 4
Sunday sell 7
Friday sell 10
```

So i am expecting it should return these data:

```
[
    [
        {
            "weekday": 7,
            "total": 11
        },
        {
            "weekday": 6,
            "total": 0
        },
        {
            "weekday": 5,
            "total": 10
        },
        {
            "weekday": 4,
            "total": 4
        },
        {
            "weekday": 3,
            "total": 0
        },
         {
            "weekday": 2,
            "total": 0
        },
         {
            "weekday": 1,
            "total": 10
        },
    ]
]
```

But problem is, it not returning data that way i want,
It is returning these:

```
[
    [
        {
            "weekday": 7,
            "total": 4
        },
        {
            "weekday": 7,
            "total": 5
        },
         {
            "weekday": 5,
            "total": 10
        },
    ]
]
```

I don't know what's wrong with this. Can anyone please help me in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query, grouping is being done on `id` first. You can confirm this by printing out the raw query: `print(weekly_sell.query)`.

This is because, when you run an annotation, django automatically groups by the `id` field of the model. So you need to add `.values("<<column>>")` to ask django ORM to group by this column instead of `id`.

You should use the following query:

```
weekly_sell = Sell.objects.annotate(
            weekday=ExtractWeekDay('date'),
        ).values(
            'weekday',
        ).annotate(
             total=Sum('total_sell')
        ).values(
             'weekday',
             'total'
        )
```

If you print out the raw query for the above queryset, you will notice that now the grouping is not on `id` and is on `weekday` instead.

Comment: For anyone coming to this, not you'll need to do `from django.db.models.functions import ExtractWeekDay` and `from django.db.models import Sum` first.